# creating DB table by giving input from php text box

Tags: php

I want to make a table in a database, by giving the name of that table as an input from a text box.

```
<?php
$tablename = $_POST['tablename'];

    // Create a MySQL table in the selected database
    mysql_query("CREATE TABLE $tablename(
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    PRIMARY KEY(id),
    firstpublish VARCHAR(255), 
    descriptions VARCHAR(255))") or die(mysql_error());  
?>
```

it makes the table and the field, but i can't insert any data in it. When i run the code below

```
<?php
$firstpublish = $_POST['firstpublish'];
$descriptions = $_POST['descriptions'];

if(isset($_POST['firstpublish']) || ($_POST['descriptions']))
    {   
$order="INSERT INTO $tablename (id,firstpublish,descriptions) VALUES ('','$firstpublish','$descriptions')";
    $result = mysql_query($order) or die (mysql_error());
    }
?>
```

it showing an error message

"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '( id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY(id), firstpublish VARCHA' at line 1"
 how can i fixed this problem.

-thankyou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is here:

```
mysql_query("CREATE TABLE $tablename(
```

Since you are mixing a variable in a quoted string, you insert whitespace after its name, because "$tablename(" is illegal name and will most likely be replaced will null, so the SQL-statement will actually be seen for MySQL as

```
CREATE TABLE id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY(id), firstpublish VARCHAR(255), descriptions VARCHAR (255))
```

which, in turn, is a syntax error.

Solution: Add a space between $tablename and "(".

Comment: adding a space between them, but still showing that error. i don't have any idea that is it the right way to write the tablename or not. :(

Comment: The table is creating successfully, but the problem about inserting data in that table.

Comment: The error you get (i.e. the one you posted here) suggests that the error lies in the creation of the table, not in the insertion of data. Are you really, really sure the table gets created? Try adding some "dummy debugging code" between the lines, like `print("Hello, I'm before the mysql_query");` and `print("Now I'm after");` etc, that will give you a better hint exactly where the error occurs.

Answer (score 1):

My best guess would be that your first query is somehow being rerun with a blank value for $tablename

If this is a publicly accessible page, i'd be very careful about creating tables from user input. You also probably want to (at the very least) run $tablenale through `mysql_real_escape_string()` and change `CREATE TABLE` to `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS`

Comment: i don't know is it the proper way to write the query of a table name? then what should i do? :(

Comment: Try wrapping your first code block with `if(!empty($_POST['tablename'])){...}`

Comment: pardon me, whats that wrapping?

Comment: Sorry, put your entire first code block inside the `if()` statement I wrote above

Comment: The table is creating successfully, but the problem about inserting data in that table. it doesn't work dear raisin. :(

Comment: Yes, but your error message indicates that it is trying to run the create query again. Putting the if() in there will prevent that if there is no value for $_POST['tablename']

Comment: yes, you right also. Just now i have fixed it. The problem was in my "$order="INSERT INTO $tablename (id,firstpublish,descriptions) VALUES ('','$firstpublish','$descriptions')";
    $result = mysql_query($order) or die (mysql_error());
" query. Alter of this, now i am using simply this inserting query " if(isset($_POST['firstpublish']) || ($_POST['descriptions']))
  { 
  mysql_query("INSERT INTO $tablename (id, firstpublish, descriptions) VALUES ('','$firstpublish','$descriptions')") or die (mysql_error());
  }" thanx dude, for your response :)